# Adding a property to an object by default

Tags: javascript

I want to add a `Symbol` property to an object for comparing.

Here is the way:

```js
let _sym = Symbol('sym');

let a = {};
a[_sym] = Symbol('_');

let b = {};
b[_sym] = Symbol('_');

console.log(a[_sym] === b[_sym]); // false
```

Both `a` and `b` are objects. So, I can write:

```js
let _sym = Symbol('sym');

Object.prototype[_sym] = Symbol('_');

Object.Equals = function (x, y) {
    return x[_sym] === y[_sym];
};

let a = {};
let b = {};

console.log(Object.Equals(a, b)); // true
```

But the result was changed.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you know what prototype on a JS object is?

Comment: @webdeb No, I don't. Based on your answer, I still don't know what it is.

Comment: @foo I would suggest learning what prototypes are as JS is prototypal based, not class based.

Comment: you are using `prototype` in your code, I would assume, that you know what it is. 1+ @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the first case you assign to every object a new symbol instance

in the second, using prototype each object shares the same property, so they are equal

to compare, this code would be equal to the second case (but only for these 2 objects):

```
let _sym = Symbol('sym');
let val = Symbol('_');

let a = {};
a[_sym] = val;

let b = {};
b[_sym] = val;

console.log(a[_sym] === b[_sym]); // true
```

Comment: Sorry, isn't it: `when an object is created, adding _sym property with value Symbol('_') to that object`? So, `Symbol('_')` is new for every time, I think.

Comment: @foo you assign reference to the property, you don't create a new symbol

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
```

Different objects

```
a === b // false
```

The same underlying prototype

```
a.toString === b.toString // true
```

Comment: it's not what I'm asking.